# Vagrant up fails, can't locate box in catalog

Tags: vagrant, puphpet, vagrant-windows

I'm running vagrant up through a file from puphpet, and the following is the message I get :

Bringing machine 'local' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> local: Box 'puphpet/ubuntu1204-x64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    local: Box Provider: virtualbox
    local: Box Version: >= 0
The box '["puphpet/ubuntu1204-x64"]' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/puphpet/ubuntu1204-x64"]
Error:

Any suggestions or fixes appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my instance, installing visual c++ runtime 2010 (X86) solved the problem.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get any suitable solution online.  While I was battling with it I just typed vagrant box add --help and I saw --insecure.
The description looked like the error message.
This worked for me
'vagrant box add --insecure ubuntu/focal64'
instead of
'vargrant box add ubuntu/focal64' .